# How to resolve cannot execute binary file:exec format error in Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, yarn-v2

I am very new to Ubuntu but had to install it because of the need to use it for a project. However, I am having some issues installing NodeJs and Yarn. I have installed it, but I cannot it access it and even when I try to check the version, I get this `execute binary file:exec format`  error.

```
root@DESKTOP-2I4LNIF:/mnt/c/Users/Dennis# apt-cache policy nodejs
nodejs:
  Installed: 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3
  Candidate: 14.20.0-deb-1nodesource1
  Version table:
     14.20.0-deb-1nodesource1 500
        500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_14.x jammy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@DESKTOP-2I4LNIF:/mnt/c/Users/Dennis# apt-cache policy yarn
yarn:
  Installed: 1.22.19-1
  Candidate: 1.22.19-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.22.19-1 500
        500 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main all Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

These are the errors I get when I try to check the version of yarn and nodejs. From the above, it seems I have installed it, but I can't see it or access it for some reason.

```
root@DESKTOP-2I4LNIF:/mnt/c/Users/Dennis# yarn -v
/usr/bin/yarn: 20: exec: node: Exec format error
root@DESKTOP-2I4LNIF:/mnt/c/Users/Dennis# nodejs -v
-bash: /usr/bin/nodejs: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
root@DESKTOP-2I4LNIF:/mnt/c/Users/Dennis#
```

I will appreciate it if anyone can help me come out of this dilemma because I am running out of time. A step-by-step approach will help.

Comment: Start by running `file /usr/bin/nodejs`. What does it show?

Comment: This is qhat I got : ```root@DESKTOP-2I4LNIF:/mnt/c/Users/Dennis# file /usr/bin/nodejs
/usr/bin/nodejs: symbolic link to node```

Comment: So what is `file /usr/bin/node`?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I honestly don't know, but from the response, gotten from the command you asked me to run, it's a symbolic link to node, which seems vague to me though.

Comment: node is a symbolic link to node? that should not be the case. anyway I would recommend to uninstall and reinstall nodejs.